# Programmatically open WORD documents using PHP +parameters

Tags: php

I am using the code below to open and process a list of word documents via php.
Problem is that, in some cases, a menu (window)  appears after opening a file.  It interrupts the script and I have to manually click cancel, etc depending on the menu.

What parameter or switches can be added to the line:-

```
$doc = $word->Documents->Open($file);
```

to suppress the menus

```
$word = new COM("word.application");

$word->Visible =false;

$doc = $word->Documents->Open($file);
```

..... etc

Thanks